# Reading non-spatial Access tables with ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I am trying to read a whole Access database into Postgis using the ogr2ogr (Version 1.9.1) command.

For some reason however, it only reads spatial tables and no non-spatial tables. All my attempts to overcome this problem so far have failed^.

I have tried configuring options such as "-nlt None" or "SET PG_LIST_ALL_TABLES=YES"

How is it possible to read ALL tables and not only the spatial tables?

This is the command I've used:

ogr2ogr --config PG_LIST_ALL_TABLES YES -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=ele_schnottwil password=bsb port=5432" C:\ele.mdb -a_srs EPSG:21781 -overwrite -skipfailures

I know PG_LIST_ALL_TABLES is a Postgis driver command but I read this could be used for the ODBC driver, too.

Can anyone see the problem or help me out.

Thanks so much in advance.

Best regards, Arne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to version 1.10 of GDAL/OGR ([GDAL: ODBC RDBMS](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_odbc.html))

```
Starting with GDAL 1.10, and on Windows provided that the "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)" ODBC 
driver is installed, non-spatial MS Access Databases (not Personnal Geodabases or Geomedia databases) 
can be opened directly by their filenames.
```